# MacOS - turning off the bash session restore

Tags: macos, terminal

I’ve tried editing /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal as well as adding files such as .bash_profiles, etc to my home folder but my session history keeps showing - when I open terminal, it will open 3 windows with its history. What to do? Thanks!

Edit: SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0 does not work as well

Comment: Adding `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0` to `~/bash_profile`, (note there's no `s` on the end of `profile` as shown in your question), works for me with macOS High Sierra. You do have to either `source` the `~/bash_profile` or close and reopen Terminal for the change to take. What version of macOS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to discard your Terminal state, you have to quit with holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. The menu will change from "Quit Terminal" to "Quit and close all windows".

[image]

You can also make it effective with the "normal" quit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, this way:

1. Open your terminal
2. Delete the content of the saved state folder: `rm -rf
   ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/*`
3. Lock the folder: `chflags uchg ~/Library/Saved\ Application\
   State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/`
4. Now, every time you quit your terminal, it won't be saved